# Poisson distribution, Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Characteristic alpha occurs in about 0.5% of a population. A random sample is to be taken without replacement from the population. How large must the sample size be to ensure that the chances exceed 90% of the sample containing a person with characteristic alpha?

I tried to answer it using the hypergeometric distribution and the Poisson distribution but no luck.

$$({0.5N \choose 1}{0.5N \choose k-1})/{N \choose k}$$

Comment: Firstly note that $0.5\%=0.005$. In my opinion the term for the inequality ( with the hypergeometric function) should be $$\frac{{0.005N \choose 1}{0.995N \choose k-1}}{{N \choose k}}>0.9$$ But I don´t see a way to solve for $k$

Comment: yes i see my error it’s using 0.5 instead of 0.005

Comment: See also the difference at the second binomial coefficient in the numerator.